# Does Java support resuming program execution after an exception?

Tags: java, exception

i would like to know how an error can be caught in java but allow the program to continue to run.

here is my example:

```
public class test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = new String("abcdefghij");
        try {
            System.out.println(str.charAt(0));
            System.out.println(str.charAt(9));
            System.out.println(str.charAt(10));
            System.out.println("is it still running");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("the index is out of bounds");
        }
    }
}
```

the following is printed:

```
a
j
the index is out of bounds
```

but after the error is thrown i would like the code to continue to run so that this is printed:

```
a
j
the index is out of bounds
is it still running
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 7):

Java does not support 'resuming' or 'restarting' after an exception.

You can wrap the specific line "to skip" in a `try/catch` (would be 3 total in the above example, one for each access) or, perhaps better, write code that will not throw an exception -- exceptions really ought to be "exceptional" IMOHO. You could also move the `try/catch` code into a method to "wrap" the access (e.g. call the method 3x), but the actions are the same.

Comment: that was kind-of what i was hoping to avoid, oh well, thanks for the info about java :)

Comment: @java For a specific problem, a(nother) question about it might be beneficial. There is a whole ton of knowledge on SO and great room for discovering different (sometimes better) approaches to a given problem within a specific set of constraints (e.g. Java).

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i =0; i < Short.MAX_VALUE; i++){
 try{
    System.out.println(str.charAt(i));
 }catch(Exception ex){}
}
```

Also you can use finally bolck if you wish to execute always.

Comment: Haha. +1 for the nice generalization.

Comment: but i don't want to print ever value, besides it would be better to make i < str.length(), that way you don't even need a try catch since it will never be out of range